# Formatting options missing after dragging cell value

Tags: excel

I have two worksheets in my workbook.

On worksheet A, when I drag a value to other cells a smart tag displays with three options:

- Copy Cells
- Fill Formatting Only
- Fill Without Formatting

On worksheet B, when I drag a value to other cells a smart tag displays with one option:

- Copy Cells

Any idea what I have done to change the behaviour? It's driving me insane..

Comment: Is worksheet B protected?

Comment: It was.. I unprotected it. Could that affect it?

Comment: Yes, protecting a worksheet can restrict a users access to formatting and other such properties.

Comment: But it's still happening now that the worksheet is unprotected.